# The converse problem about duality of $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $Ω$ be a bounded open subset in $R^n$ and $f$ be measureable with respect to Lebesgue measure on $Ω$. If there exist $M＞0$ s.t.$$\left|\int fg\,\mathrm{d}x\right|≦M\left(\int |g|^q\mathrm{d}x\right)^\frac{1}{q}$$ for all continuous function $g$ on $Ω$ (the integral is on $Ω$), where $1＜q＜+∞$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, then $f \in L^p(Ω)$ and $\|f\|_{L^p(Ω)}≦M$.

I find some references: the conclusion is true if $g$ can be substituted by all simple functions.

> But how can we do this in the continuous case? Should we choose simple functions that approximate the continuous $g$ by using Lusin's theorem  (but I have some problem in seeing how to do this)? Could someone show me the details? Thank you!

*My doubt*: even though we can use a continuous $g$ to approximate simple functions in $L^1$ (i.e. in the left side integral), we need that to prove they are close enough also in $L^q$ (i.e. in the right side integral).

Comment: Could you tell me from where you have the proof for simple functions?

Comment: I find the simple function case in the book of Chinese book .The Language is Chinese. I will show you a picture.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I can figure it out although I am german xD

Comment: I am sorry that I type words very slowly .I need several hours to  type it out .

Comment: Ah I see how the proof works: There is a problem though. In the book, the author chose an INCREASING sequence $\varphi_k$ that converges to $\lvert g(x) \rvert^{p'}$ pointwise a.e.. The question is if such a sequence also exists if we choose continuous functions...

Comment: The author use the definition of Lebesgue integral. I only remind  to use Lusin' theorem or compacted supproted continuous function dense in $L^p$.

Comment: I could figure it out if I managed to prove that $f$ is bounded. Do you have an idea to prove this?

Comment: The measure of whole space is finite.  If $f$ is bounded ,We only need to prove its norm is less than $M$ may be I can use Dominant Convergence Theorem

Comment: What I wanted to do was to approximate $\mathrm{sgn}(f)\lvert f \rvert^{p-1}$ by continuous functions in $L^q(\Omega)$. But I can not do this, unless I know if $f$ is in $L^p(\Omega)$...

Comment: For $g$ continuous, even though we try to approximate $sgn(f)|f|^p$, we may not get the norm of $f$ in $L^p$  less than $M$ . My idea is try to choose a continuous close enough to the continuous function $g$. If $f$ is bounded, we still can get its norm is little larger than $M$. Well may be my idea is invalid.

Comment: Not invalid. But we do not know if $f$ is bounded, that's the issue.

Comment: I need to correct it:Try to choose a continuous function close enough to simple function $g$.

Comment: The ordinary problem doesn't gives us the condiction that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: My be I can choose a continuous function g close enough to each simple function in $L^q$ . By Holider inequality, they are close enough in $L^1$ since the measure of total space is finite. Then we can use the reference.

Comment: My proof is typed on the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\ds\displaystyle$

Since continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^q(\Omega)$, the inequality
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
\bigg|\int_\Omega fg\bigg|\leq M\,\|g\|_q$$ holds for all $g\in L^q$ (proof at the end).

Suppose that $\int_\Omega|f|^p=\infty$. Let
$$
X_n=\{|f|\leq n\},\qquad n\in\mathbb N.
$$
Then $\Omega=\bigcup_nX_n$. Write $f(x)=|f(x)|\,e^{i\theta(x)}$. Define
$$
g_n=\frac{e^{-i\theta}\,|f|^{p-1}\,1_{X_n}}{\bigg(\ds\int_{X_n}|f|^p\Bigg)^{1/q}}.
$$
Then
$$
\|g_n\|_q^q=\frac{\ds\int_{X_n}|f|^{q(p-1)}}{\ds\int_{X_n}|f|^p }=1.
$$
And
$$
\int_\Omega f\,g_n=\frac{\ds\int_{X_n}|f|^p}{\bigg(\ds\int_{X_n}|f|^p\Bigg)^{1/q}}=\bigg(\ds\int_{X_n}|f|^p\Bigg)^{1-1/q}=\bigg(\ds\int_{X_n}|f|^p\Bigg)^{1/p}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\bigg(\int_\Omega|f|^p\Bigg)^{1/p}=\infty,
$$
contradicting your inequality. So $f\in L^p$.

---

*Proof of \eqref{1}*. Given $g\in L^q(\Omega)$ there exists a sequence $\{h_n\}$ such that $\|g-h_n\|_q\to0$ (proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/226070/22857) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3018261/22857)).  Then there exists a subsquence, that we still name $\{h_n\}$ that converges pointwise almost everywhere. Then using Fatou's Lemma,
$$
\bigg|\int_\Omega fg\bigg|=\bigg|\int_\Omega \lim_nfh_n\bigg|\leq\liminf_n\bigg|\int_\Omega fh_n\bigg|\leq\liminf_n M\|h_n\|_q=M\|g\|_q.
$$
The last equality is due to $\big|\|g\|_q-\|h_n\|_q\big|\leq\|g-h_n\|_q$ by the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Since continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^q(\Omega)$, the inequality holds for all $g\in L^q$(Why the equality still hold in $L^q$? I think it is hard for me to prove this).

Comment: Yes, it's less obvious than I thought.It probably works, though. And another possibility is to tweak my $g_n$ slightly via Lusin so that it is continuous; but it requires some care and I'll have to think about it.

Comment: This step is very hard for me. Even though  we can use continuous g to appxomimate simple function in $L^1$(Left hand side integral), we need try to get they are close enough in $L^q$(the right hand side integral).

Comment: My be I can choose a continuous function g close enough to each simple function in $L^q$ . By Holider inequality, they are close enough in $L^1$ since the measure of total space is finite. Then we can use the reference.

Comment: I think I finish the proof.

Comment: I completed my argument. About yours, steps 1 and 2 are not clear to me. The "other part" maybe very small, but $f$ could be very big there; I don't see how you could control that.

Comment: $f$ is integral. We can use the continuity of integral. There exist $δ＞0$,$\ intEfdx＜ε$ if $m(E)＜δ$. Then use Lusin Theorem.

Comment: $ \int_ E fdx＜ε$

Comment: But you also want to control how bounded $f$ is on the complement. Why don't you write the argument?

Comment: For the given $δ$,  there is a closed (thus compact) set $E_δ$ ,  $f$ is continuous on $E_δ$ and $m(Ω\E_δ)＜δ$ by Lusin. The integral is very small by Holider inequality for the first part, and the integral is close to 0 by the continuity of integral in the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract: In this article, the norm in $L^p(\Omega)$ space could be descriped by all continuous functions in theorem 1 on $ \Omega $, where  $ \Omega $ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R} ^n$, $1<p<\infty$. This could be regard as the converse problem for H{"o}lder inequality.

Theorem 1. $ \Omega $ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R} ^n$, $1<q<\infty$, $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $ \Omega $. If there exist a $M>0$ s.t.
\begin{equation}
 |\int_{\Omega} fgdx|\leq M(\int_{\Omega} |g|^qdx)^\frac{1}{q} 
\end{equation}
then, $f\in L^p(\Omega)$,  $||f||_p \leq M$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and $||\;||_p$ denote the norm in $L^p(\Omega)$

Proof:

Claim 1. if the continuous funtion  could be sbustituted by all integrable simple functions in (1), then the results hold . We can get it from reference 1.

Claim 2. $|x^p-y^p|\leq p|x-y|(x^{p-1}+y^{p-1})$ when $1<p<\infty$, Real and Complex Analysis Rudin's book in chapter 3, problem 24.

We only need to show
\begin{equation}
  |\int_{\Omega} fhdx|\leq M(\int_{\Omega} |h|^qdx)^\frac{1}{q} 
 \end{equation}
for all integrable simple function $h$ by claim 1. Thus we only need to prove the inequality (2).

case 1.   $\int_{\Omega} |f|=0$, (2) is trivial.

case 2.   $\int_{\Omega} |f|\neq0 $
for any $\epsilon >0$, we choose a bounded continuous function $g$.(Choose a real number $G$ s.t. $h,g$ are bounded by $G$) s.t.$\int_{\Omega}|h-g|^qdx<2\epsilon$

Claim 3. $ \int _{\Omega}|f(h-g)|dx<\epsilon$

We have $\int_{\Omega}|h^p-g^p|dx<4p\epsilon G^(p-1)$ by Claim 2.
Now we have
$$|\int_{\Omega} fhdx|\leq M(\epsilon)(\int_{\Omega} |h|^qdx)^\frac{1}{q} $$
and $M(\epsilon)$ is bigger but close enough to $M$ by claim 1.,2.and 3.
Let $\epsilon $ converges to $0$. We  have proved the inequality (2) and complete the proof.

Proof of claim 1.
(I translate the reference into English):

We choose compact supported nonnegative simple measurables function sequence ${\phi_k(x)}$ ($0\leq\phi_1(x)\leq\phi_2\leq...\leq \infty$) s.t. $$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\phi_k(x)=|f|^p,x\in \Omega$$
Let $\psi_k(x)=(\phi_k(x))^\frac{1}{q} \text{sign} f(x)$,
$$||\psi_k||_q=(\int_{\Omega}\psi_k(x)dx)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
$$0\leq\psi_k(x)=(\psi_k(x))^{\frac{1}{q}}(\psi_k(x))^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq(\psi_k(x))^{\frac{1}{q}}|f(x)|=\psi_k(x)f(x)$$
So, we have
$$\int_{\Omega}\phi_k(x)dx\leq\int_{\Omega}\psi_k(x)f(x)\leq M||\psi_k(x)||_q$$.
Thus
$$\int_{\Omega}\phi_k(x)dx\leq M^p $$.
After taking the limit, we have
$$\int_{\Omega}|f(x)|^pdx\leq M^p $$.

Proof of claim 2.

$f$ is integrable, then there exist $\delta>0$ s.t. $\int_{E} |f|<\frac{1}{2G}\epsilon$
Then there exist closed $E_{\delta}\subset \Omega$ and $m(\Omega \backslash E_{\delta})<\delta$. The integral on $E_{\delta})$ is dominated by  H{"o}lider inequality.

Answer (score 1):

There is a functional analysis proof: Let $F: C_0(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the linear map
$$
F(g) := \int_\Omega fg~\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Because of the given estimate, $F$ is a linear, continuous functional with respect to the $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^q(\Omega)}$-norm and $\lVert F \rVert \leq M$. Since $C_0(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^q(\Omega)$, there is a [*unique* continuous, linear extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838692/extensions-of-bounded-linear-operators/2838786) $\tilde{F} \in L^q(\Omega)'$ such that
$$
\tilde{F}(g) = \int_\Omega f g~\mathrm{d}x 
$$
for all $g\in C_0(\Omega)$ and $\lVert \tilde{F} \rVert \leq M$.
By the [characterisation of $L^q(\Omega)'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709035/duality-of-lp-spaces), there is exactly one $\tilde{f} \in L^p(\Omega)$ with $\lVert \tilde{f} \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)} = \lVert \tilde{F} \rVert \leq M$ such that
$$
\tilde{F}(\zeta) = \int_\Omega \tilde{f}\zeta~\mathrm{d}x
$$
for all $\zeta \in L^q(\Omega)$. Thus
$$
\tilde{F}(g) = \int_\Omega \tilde{f}g~\mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega fg~\mathrm{d}x
$$
for all $g \in C_0(\Omega)$. Therefore $\tilde{f} = f$ by the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations.

So $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ with $\lVert f \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq M$.